# How do I add a link to an external marketing video to the site home page?

Tags: javascript, python, plone

I'm not much of a programmer and I need some assistance in adding an external link to the home page of my site. It's a JavaScript hosted on a provider's site that will integrate a marketing video on my site (Plone 3.2).

I looked at the **portal_javascripts** registry, but I'm not clear on how to ensure the link is only run on the home page.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript registry fill the condition field with this expression:

```
python:(folder.meta_type=='Plone Site') and (context.getId()==folder.getDefaultPage())
```

Where:

- `context` is the current object.
- `folder` is the container for current object. In case of objects in Plone site root, it is the site itself.
- `folder.meta_type` is the portal type of the container.
- `folder.getDefaultPage()` gets the container's default page. In case the container is the Plone site, it is the home page of your site.

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript registry, use a "condition" (if you mean you're editing through the ZMI) or "expression" (if you're doing this in javascripts.xml via GenericSetup) of

```
python:context.portal_url() == context.absolute_url()
```

There are better ways - you should really be testing if the interface Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.siteroot.IPloneSiteRoot is provided_by context:

```
>>> from Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.siteroot import IPloneSiteRoot 
>>> IPloneSiteRoot.providedBy(context)
True
```

but I'm not sure how to do that in a portal_javascripts condition.